# A word meaning "the state of obeying a rule"

Tags: single-word-requests, word-usage

Is there a word that means "the state of obeying a rule".

I'm thinking since it can be said that something 'adheres' to a rule that 'adherent' would fit the bill, but somehow it doesn't sound quite right.

For example
"It adheres to the rule." -> "It is adherent."
or
"Does it adhere to the rule." -> "Yes, it is adherent."

Is is correct or acceptable to use the word 'adherent' in such a manner?

Comment: You can say 'It is adherent *to the rule'*, but simply saying 'It is adherent' seems to me like a non sequitur.

Comment: It complies with the rule; it is compliant.

Comment: *Compliant* as toandfro suggested; *rule-bound* though correct, is now also used in a negative sense of being overly tied down by rules.

Comment: It either fits the rule, or it does not.

Comment: Adherents are usually religious folk.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Compliance --> compliant

> We need to comply. This setting is **in compliance with** rules and
>   regulations.

-

> We were **following the** rules. We were obedient. **Obeying the** law can get
>   you in trouble, not obeying also.

Looking up obey in the thesaurus http://thesaurus.com/browse/obey the following came to mind.

> **Adherance to** rules is good and necessary in order to be in adherence
>   with the rules.

Answer (score 1):

***rule-bound***, *rule bound*

Coker, [*Business owner's response*](http://www.caller.com/news/2013/jan/08/business-owners-response-to-unhappy-customer-key/?print=1) caller.com Jan. 8, 2013

> Some of us are rule bound. We obey the social exchange rules diligently and we expect all others to do likewise. **Rule bound people** believe, rightfully, that we can't have successful interaction in relationships that are mutually beneficial to both parties if one party violates the social exchange rules.

Sobel, *Taking Chances* 1994, [p.121](http://books.google.co.in/books?id=WakwjkcY1ScC&pg=PA121&lpg=PA121&dq=%22rule-bound%20person%22&source=bl&ots=AtCz16Nelo&sig=UL5hXFKtoVnH21zrUtxsLcYkgl8&hl=en&sa=X&ei=ZWg2U5v7DMbnrAelk4G4Bw&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22rule-bound%20person%22&f=false)

> The **rule-bound person** could have better options amongst which to choose in his choice situations.

*Rule-bound*, though correct, is now also used in a negative sense of being overly tied down by rules. *Compliant* on the other hand is too mild.

Answer (score 0):

How about the word "obedient", for without a preexisting rule, there would be nothing to obey.